# search the whole git subcommands, guides and overview man pages

Tags: bash, git

We can search whole man page using `man -wK`.

We can get the git subcommands using `git help -a`. We can get common git guides using `git help -g`.

For an overview of the system we can use `git help git`. To check the man page of a particular subcommand we can use, for example `git help add`. To check the man page of a particular guides we can use, for example `git help cli`.

I am interested to search the whole git (its subcommands, guides and overview man pages).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually:

- clone https://github.com/git/git
- go to the `Documentation` folder
- do a `git grep "The-term-I-want-know-about"`

That will search in all:

- how-to guides
- technical guides
- release notes
- man pages

Comment: The release notes was very important. Thanks.

Comment: Optionally also checkout the tag corresponding to your installed git(1).

Answer (score 1):

For commands (not guides):

```
git --list-cmds=main,builtins | xargs -n 1 -I {} man git {} | cat | less
```

You could also expand that list.

For guides:

```
git --list-cmds=list-guide | xargs -n 1 -I {} man git{} | cat | less
```

That’s a separate invocation since those are spelled e.g. `giteveryday`.

If you want both of them at the same time:

```
cmds=$(mktemp)
git --list-cmds=main,builtins | xargs -n 1 -I {} man git {} | cat > $cmds
guides=$(mktemp)
git --list-cmds=list-guide | xargs -n 1 -I {} man git{} | cat > $guides
cat $cmds $guides | less
rm $cmds $guides
```